# How to bind on_selection_change in a .kv file (Kivy, listadapter)

Tags: python, kivy, listadapter

I am having trouble finding a way to bind the on_selection_change function of ListView to a list adapter in Kivy.  This is for when you select a certain list item, a function is called.  The docs say it can be done in a .py file this way:

```
list_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=callback_function)
```

But, my whole program is split between a .py and .kv files.  My program does not use the pure python way, or Builder.load_string(""" """) way of coding for kivy.  I am wondering if there is a way to bind the on_selection_change to a list adapter if you are using the .kv language.  Example of my .kv file :

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 2, 1
        ListView:
            id: demo_list_view
            size_hint: 1, 1
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=sorted([]),
                selection_mode="single",
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                cls=ListItemButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an action inside .kv file.
Just look here: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html (section "Designing with the Kivy Language").
For example:

```
Button:
        text: 'Button'
        on_press: root.do_action()
```

And do_action() is defined in .py file inside button's root class:

```
def do_action(self):
    pass
```

Or you can define *action* inside widget class (.py file) and use *self.action()* (.kv).

Moreover, you can use some python code right inside .kv file, as long as it doesn't need new idetation level.

Example:

```
on_press: root.do_action()
          for i in range(10): pass
```

But you can't:

```
on_press: root.do_action()
          for i in range(10):
              pass
```

Not a full answer, but I can't comment, so I leave it there.